# Porting linux for a custom RISC-V imafd SOC

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, yocto, riscv, openembedded

I am trying to build a yocto **demo-coreip-cli** image for my custom risc-v SOC which only supports **imafd** instructions.
For the compilation of cross toolchain that is used by Bitbake, I tried changing cross-binutils.inc recipe and cross-gcc.inc recipe in openembedded-core layer by including “**–with-arch=rv64imafd**” in "**EXTRA_OECONF** " variable.
Is there anything else I am missing or doing wrong?
Thank You.

Comment: It's not clear for me if it's woking now, or what is the error.

Comment: No, its not working. On running the compiled executable on the imafd board, Its giving "illegal instructions" error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully port the image to RV64-imafd.
You can follow this [link](https://forums.sifive.com/t/porting-linux-for-a-custom-imafd-soc/3925) for the steps I followed.
Atlast I compiled all the changes into a separate layer and .bbappend files.
Let me know if I can help any further.